# Docker Compose, Add MySQL support to PHP-FPM 7. Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker Compose to build my first Docker machine. I want setup Docker to have PHP-FPM 7, Nginx and MySQL (Using MariaDB).

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
nginx:
image: nginx:latest
ports:
  - "80:80"
volumes:
  - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
  - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
  - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html
links:
  - phpfpm

phpfpm:
image: php:7-fpm
volumes:
  - ./public:/usr/share/nginx/html
  - ./logs/log.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-log.conf

mariadb:
image: mariadb
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
  MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
  MYSQL_USER: admin
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
volumes:
 - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
```

Docker starts up correctly but when I try using mysql_connect to connect to the database in index.php I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php on line 7

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
 $username = "admin";
 $password = "admin";
 $hostname = "localhost";

 //connection to the database
 $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
   or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
 echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
 ?>
```

How can I set up PHP-FPM to use MySQL?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In php7 `mysql` extension is removed. Over.

Comment: You should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: `How can I set up PHP-FPM to use MySQL?` Use a proper extension, like MySQLi or PDO. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every time you use [the `mysql_`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) database extension in new code,
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)**, it is deprecated and has been for years and is **gone forever in PHP7**.

You will have to install a PHP5.6 version OR better refactor your code to use MYSQLI or PDO

Comment: I would give even more up vote if I even could, for the sake of saving kittens.